# Labeling rows in pandas using multiple boolean conditions without chaining

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to label data in the original dataframe, based on multiple boolean conditions. This is easy enough when labeling based on one or two conditions, but as I begin requiring multiple conditions the code becomes difficult to manage. The solution seems to break the code down into copies, but that causes chain errors. Here is one example of the issue...

This is a simplified version of what my data looks like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['ABC',1,3,3,4], ['std',0,0,2,4],['std',2,1,2,4],['std',4,4,2,4],['std',2,6,2,6]]), columns=['Note', 'Na','Mg','Si','S'])
df
   Note Na  Mg  Si  S
0   ABC 1   3   3   4
1   std 0   0   2   4
2   std 2   1   2   4
3   std 4   4   2   4
4   std 2   6   2   6
```

A standard (std) is located throughout the dataframe. I would like to create a label when the instrument fails. This occurs in the data when:

1. String condition met (Note = standard/std)
2. Na>0 & Mg>0
3. Doesn't fall outside of a calculated range for more than 2 elements.

For requirement 3 - Here is an example of a range:

```
maxMin=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Max',3,3,3,7], ['Min',1,1,2,2]]), columns=['Note', 'Na','Mg','Si','S'])
maxMin
    Note    Na  Mg  Si  S
0   Max      3  3   3   7
1   Min      1  1   2   2
```

Calculating out of bound standard:

```
elements=['Na','Mg','Si','S']
std=df[(df['Note'].str.contains('std|standard'))&(df['Na']>0)&(df['Mg'])
df.loc[(std[elements].lt(maxMin.loc[1, :])|std[elements].gt(maxMin.loc[0, :]).select_dtypes(include=['bool'])).sum(axis=1)>2]

   Note Na  Mg  Si  S
3   std 4   4   2   4
```

Now, I would like to label this datapoint within the original dataframe. Desired result:

```
   Note Na  Mg  Si  S   Error
0   ABC 1   3   3   4   False
1   std 0   0   2   4   False
2   std 2   1   2   4   False
3   std 4   4   2   4   True
4   std 2   6   2   6   False

I've tried things like:
df['Error'].loc[std.loc[(std[elements].lt(maxMin.loc[1, :])|std[elements].gt(mMmaxMinloc[0, :]).select_dtypes(include=['bool'])).sum(axis=1)>5].index.values.copy()]=True
```

That unfortunately causes a chain error.

How would you accomplish this without creating a chain error? Most books/tutorial revolve around creating one long expression, but as I dive deeper, I feel there might be a simpler solution. Any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out a solution that works for me.

The solution was to use `.index.value` to create an array of the index that passed the bool conditions. That array can be used to pass edit the original dataframe.

```
##These two conditions can probably be combined
condition1=df[(df['Note'].str.contains('std|standard'))&(df['Na']>.01)&(df['Mg']>.01)]

##where condition1 is greater/less than the bounds of the known value.
##provides array where condition is true
OutofBounds=condition1.loc[(condition1[elements].lt(maxMin.loc[1, :])|condition1[elements].gt(maxMin.loc[0, :]).select_dtypes(include=['bool'])).sum(axis=1)>5].index.values
OutofBounds
out:array([    3], dtype=int64)
```

Now I can pass the array into the original dataframe:

```
df.loc[OutofBounds, 'Error']=True
```